# CakePHP authentication 3 quick start, does it actually create add.php?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Following [the CakePHP authentication quick start guide](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/3/en/index.html), it ends with

> You should now be able to go to /users/add and register a new user.

When I go to that URL, it says

> The view for UsersController::add() was not found.

Did I miss something or did the quick start guide never create it?

Comment: try Users/add.php

Comment: I think you have to create the controller (Controller/UsersController.php) and the template (templates/Users/add.php). You can use cake bake